# SVNNotifier Source File errors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, svn

I would like to add an automatic/constant checkout in `SVNNotifier` and I downloaded their Open Source Code to change it. It is the first time that I try to modify an open source code.

I want to add a checkbox called "AutoCheckout" in the update section, but I get this error message which I don't understand:

Error   1   The type 'CHD.SVN_Notifier.SettingsForm' already contains a definition for 'checkBox_AutoCheckout'  C:\Users\conrad.chamerski\Documents\SVNNotifier\SVN_Notifier\SettingsForm.cs    1189    22  SVN_Notifier

What I don't understand is that there is a region with a bunch of code:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_SVNpath;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_TortoiseSVNpath;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_OK;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_Cancel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_BrowseSvn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_BrowseTortoise;
        private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog_svn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog_Tortoise;
```

And there is more...
But Where are the definitions of the checkboxes?

My checkbox code added below the `SettingsForm.cs`

```
private void checkBox_AutoCommit(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("AutoCommit");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake which was due to lack of knowledge.

The application form is simple, there is no coding necessary. After checking the box, we usually press the `OK butto`. The OK button has `events` which is the `thunderbolt icon` located in `properties`. By double clicking the click property, we get all the code. Now, we know what is happening when OK is pressed and we can configure this.